# how to add custom reviews button in woocommerce order complete generated mail

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, email

this is possible in woocommerce order complete generated mail...? i m Adding a review button in order complete generated mail for review about product ..it means after checkout process then send to also email to customer to all detail about billing and in this email i m adding also a custom review button in last.. if customer click to this button they directly go to our product page and give review to his product or all other product....but i don't know where i go and add to this button and all this function ..so please help me to add this custom button

i m trying so hard but not add this button .....if this is possible so please help me to put this custom review button in woocommerce order complete generated mail

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite [woocommerce templates](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/tree/release/3.2/templates/emails) placing them in your theme. To overwrite e.g. `email-order-details.php` template, place it in `yourtheme/woocommerce/email/email-order-details.php` path.

You can also add [action](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/3.2/templates/emails/email-order-details.php#L74) to add your custom review button.

```
function wpse_287685_woocommerce_email_after_order_table($order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email) {
    ?>
        <a href="#">Add review</a>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'wpse_287685_woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: You have to place it in your theme files like functions.php not woocommerce files.

Comment: What you mean by "others"? Do you want to add "Add review" button in some different places?

Comment: Yes, you have to add only this part of code to your functions.php to add `<a href="#">Add review</a>` button.